# how to return result from a function to component in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to return the value of a function to the component in reactjs. The console.log within the function is getting displayed but the result is not getting returned. I am having trouble in this scenario everytime. Can any one please help me out.

Below is my code. Am unable to display the Waveform tag that is supposed to be returned from the function encodedAudioFilename()

```
const PopUpModal = props => {
   .....

   some code
   .....

function encodedAudioFilename(){
    const regex = /(?<=recordings\/).+/gm;
    let m;

    while ((m = regex.exec(audioLocation)) !== null) {
     
        // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
        if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
            regex.lastIndex++;
        }
        // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
        m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
            console.log("https://d30pkmxa7non58.cloudfront.net/"+encodeURIComponent(match));
            
            return <Waveform src={"https://d30pkmxa7non58.cloudfront.net/"+encodeURIComponent(match) }/>
        });
    }
  }

return (
 <ModalBody>
          <div className="wave-player">
          {encodedAudioFilename()}
        </div>
</ModalBody>
)
 
};
export default PopUpModal;
```

Comment: First of all. youi'l have to use list Map fucntion because forEach doesn't returns anything.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I did not realize I was using forEach. Using Map resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your function actually doesn't return anything

Try below code

```
function encodedAudioFilename(){
    const regex = /(?<=recordings\/).+/gm;
    let m;

    let ar = [];
    while ((m = regex.exec(audioLocation)) !== null) {
     
        // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
        if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
            regex.lastIndex++;
        }
        // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
        arr = m.map((match, groupIndex) => {
            console.log("https://d30pkmxa7non58.cloudfront.net/"+encodeURIComponent(match));
            
            return <Waveform key={groupIndex} src={"https://d30pkmxa7non58.cloudfront.net/"+encodeURIComponent(match) }/>
        });
        arr = [...ar, ...arr];
    }
    return ar;
  }
```